# Asynchronous computation and save in django 3 models

Tags: python-3.x, django, asynchronous

I have a problem making part of my models asynchronous in Django 3.

This is my **models.py**:

```
class ModelImages(models.Model):
    case = models.ForeignKey(Case, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                          related_name="slice_img")
    img = models.ImageField(editable=False)
    #other

def get_slices(instance):
    # operations
    return images_array_list

def process_3d_image(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        imgs = get_slices(instance)
        for img in imgs:
            # other operations
            case_img = ModelImages(case=instance, img=name)
            with transaction.atomic():
                case_img.save()

post_save.connect(process_3d_image, sender=Case)
```

The code is longer but I reported only the crucial parts.
It works correctly but I want to make 'process_3d_image' function asynchronous.
I tried Celery, Trio, and others without any result.

How could I do it?

Edit: I would like to do it with built-in **async**, **asyncio** and uvicorn, if possible.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the asynchronous task managers you tried didn't work?

Comment: Celery did not work mostly because of circular import problems. When I put 'process_3d_image' in **tasks.py**, I cannot call **ModelImages** from there because it tells me something like **cannot import name 'ModelImages' from partially initialized module 'something.models' (most likely due to a circular import )**
I tried everything but did not work.